# How do I register global variables independently in a single global array

Tags: c++, design-patterns, global-variables, factory-pattern

I'm writing this, well, call it a library I guess. It offers a set of global variables of type MyType. Now, I want to write the source of each of these MyType's in its own `.cpp` and `.h` files, unaware of all the rest, without needing some central header file saying `MyType* offerings = { &global1, &global2, /*... */ }`.

Now, had these been different classes I want to be able to instantiate, I would want to use a factory pattern; but here they're all of the same type, and I don't need to instantiate anything. I would think each variable needs to be 'registered' into a global array (or unordered set) from somewhere in its sources.

So, what's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Do you think you could add a `Write()` function to `MyType` that takes a path as an argument? Then the class itself would be responsible for writing itself to the file?

Comment: @AndyG: I believe you misunderstood what I meant. Clarified the wording.

Comment: Ah, I understand a little better now. What I still don't follow is that, if they are all of the same type, then I don't understand how/why you would need separate .h or .cpp files for each.

Comment: @AndyG: 1. Because they're written by different people at different times. 2. Because there are a lot of them. 3. Because they cluster well into related groups which share some of their code.

Comment: I think I was unclear. What I meant was that you only need a single .h/.cpp file for a class, so why is there more than one? When you say `MyType` do you actually mean `MyType1`, `MyType2`, `MyType3`..., etc? And perhaps they all derive from the same base class or something?

Comment: @AndyG: Since different people don't share the same source files. Someone writes `eyals-mytypes.cpp`/`.h` and someone else writes `andys-mytypes.cpp`/`.h` , and maybe they go into different dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Registry Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RegistryPattern) and create a manager for your filesystem or folder that will manage these objects.

The Registry could have everything related to Filesystem Handling so you insert your object names and properties in a model in one config file or database. The registry could look up that and instantiate your objects on runtime.

Now you would need a mechanism to communicate this objects to the rest of the system. But if your objects are not going to change then just a registry with compile time objects would do.

The Registry is a pattern to handle global objects in a similar fashion to the singleton.